# Error "could not get debug privilege, are you admin" on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm having problems installing Auto CAD and 3D Max on Windows 8.1. It's giving me an error saying that it "could not get the debug privilege" and asking "are you admin?".

What should I do?

Comment: It's telling you that you are not the administrator and therefore are not allowed to do the operation

Comment: Are the versions of the software Windows 8.1 compliant?  Version info on the applications may give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program Windows inherits the privileges from the parent process. The shell runs with lower privileges, so all programs also run with lower privileges (filtered token) because of the [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

To Run a program as admin, you have to make a right click and select ["Run as administrator"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token).

Comment: did but still same issue?

Comment: run the **local security policy** MMC snapin and look if the debug  privilege is assigned to the admin group.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on Setup
- Select 'Troubleshoot compatibility'
- Troubleshoot the program
- Check the checkbox "the program requires additional permissions".

The problem should be solved.

Comment: Where is this ''setup'' thingie that you suggest that we click on?